# jQuery UI : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, jquery-ui

I use jQUery UI Dialog: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ (that i added manually to a preject web Forms .net) to display a description text on a web page. This is my current code:

.aspx:

```
<span id="bullAide" runat="server" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign text-info" style="cursor: pointer;"></span>
<div id="dialog" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="TitreCourriel">
  <p id="txtDescription" runat="server"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("TexteCourriel.Text").ToString()%></p>
</div>
```

.js:

```
$("[id$=dialog]").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    position: {
        of: $('#bullAide'),
    },
});
$("[id$=bullAide]").click(function (event) {
    setTimeout(function () { $("[id$=dialog]").dialog("open"); }, 1);
    var position = $(this).offset();
    $("[id$=dialog]").parent().css("left", position.left + 30);
    $("[id$=dialog]").parent().css("top", position.top - 30);
    setTimeout(function () { $("[id$=dialog]").parent().css("width", "auto"); }, 1);
});
```

Howerver, i have this error : Uncaught TypeError:

```
Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined
    at s (http://localhost/FIAF.PES.Particuliers/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js:6:11536)
    at jQuery.fn.init.t.fn.position (http://localhost/FIAF.PES.Particuliers/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js:6:13371)
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._position (http://localhost/FIAF.PES.Particuliers/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js:11:7019)
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._position (http://localhost/FIAF.PES.Particuliers/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js:6:4499)
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).open (http://localhost/FIAF.PES.Particuliers/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js:11:937)
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).open (http://localhost/FIAF.PES.Particuliers/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js:6:4499)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost/FIAF.PES.Particuliers/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js:6:5446)
    at Function.each (http://localhost/FIAF.PES.Particuliers/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js:368:19)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (http://localhost/FIAF.PES.Particuliers/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js:157:17)
    at jQuery.fn.init.t.fn.(anonymous function) [as dialog] (http://localhost/FIAF.PES.Particuliers/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js:6:5329)
```

I really dont know what is wrong !

Comment: Maybe you are using a not compatible version of jquery ui...can you tell us your jquery ui version?....maybe you are using a version of jquery that is too high.

Comment: i use jquery-3.1.1 and jquery-ui-1.12.0

Comment: Why those (strange) "id ends with ..." selectors, especially when the ids are the same as the "end" you're matching against? And what is with the `setTimeout()` calls?

Comment: The error *looks* like your `#dialog` doesn't have a parent - is it inside another div?  Do you have multiple dialogs and some aren't yet fully attached?  What do you get with `console.log($("[id$=dialog]").length)`.  Can you change it to `$("#dialog")` to be sure you're only getting the one dialog that you intend to get.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] showing it failing?

Comment: You can check this example https://jsfiddle.net/ncrp2z1x/

Comment: As @Hackerman 's fiddle confirms and my questions imply, there is nothing wrong with the code that you've provided in this question.  The issue is with code that is in your application that you've not included here.   Working through a a minimal, complete example will likely help you to find your issue.   As it is, there's not much more we can help with here.

Comment: my ids are fine, i have to use the "id ends with ..." because .net generates an id like this "ContentPlaceHolder1_dialog". [id$=dialog]").length guives me 1and my #dialog doesn't have a parent like the example in this link ( http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ )

Comment: @N.BenOthmen the concern here is if there is more than 1 item selected. You may consider `var $diag = $("[id$='dialog']");`

Answer (score 1):

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/q0kebgwd/

**HTML**

```
<p style="display: inline-block;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent arcu nisi, maximus eget lectus at, egestas pellentesque lectus. Donec varius tristique nunc eu dapibus. Phasellus urna massa, malesuada eu mi eget, vehicula cursus massa. Donec eu fringilla mi. Mauris leo tellus, vestibulum at ex sit amet, aliquam tincidunt lectus. Fusce blandit ex non sapien tempor fringilla. Donec leo ante, faucibus sed suscipit quis, bibendum convallis nulla. Suspendisse blandit dignissim ipsum. Suspendisse consectetur, quam sit amet placerat rhoncus, nisl nunc efficitur magna, ut rhoncus lectus felis ut velit.<span id="bullAide" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign text-info" style="cursor: pointer; margin-left: 3px;"></span></p>
<div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dialog" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="TitreCourriel">
  <p id="txtDescription" runat="server">This is a test</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var $diag = $("[id$='dialog']")
  $diag.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    position: {
      my: "left top",
      at: "left+30 top-30",
      of: $("[id$='bullAide']")
    },
  });
  $("[id$='bullAide']").click(function(event) {
    $diag.dialog("open");
  });
});
```

This will help you position the dialog properly. The error may be a result of a missing parent or issues ascending the DOM in your code. This stripped down code should work. I also set the example to match your library versions.